# SQL query to find the last closed seq_id for each workorder

Tags: sql, sql-server

As I am not expert in writing the SQL queries so want for help.

I have the below given dataset.

I need to write a query to find the "last closed seq_id for each workorder"

The final query should return rows only with seq_id = 24,28,32
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUNZ0.png)

Comment: Why 31 instead of 32?

Comment: what is the sql server version

Comment: my bad it , it should be 32

Comment: @surendra, 2008 version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select max value of each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510185/select-max-value-of-each-group)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT   sts
        ,workorder_id
        ,MAX(SEQ_ID) AS Last_Seq_ID
FROM mytablename
WHERE sts = 'Closed' -- Only include Closed records
GROUP BY sts, workorder_id
ORDER BY workorder_id -- This line is optional; it will sort your result
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
SELECT workorder_id
      ,max(seq_id) 
from   your_table 
where  sts="Closed" 
group by workorder_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you really mean "32" rather than "31", then `row_number()` is the typical method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by workorder_id order by seq_id desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where sts = 'Closed'
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select workorder_id,max(seq_id) as seqid
from testtable 
where sts='Closed'
group by workorder_id
```