# MS SQL Server select rows with max values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Good day

I have `Table1:`

```
COLUMN1    COLUMN2   Column3  
----------------------------
Eva           Apple       1
Eva           Apple       2
Eva           Apple       3
Eva           Apple       4
Eva           Apple       5
Eva           Apple       6
Bob           Apple       1
Bob           Samsung     1
Bob           Samsung     2
...           ...        ...
```

I need

```
COLUMN1    COLUMN2   Column3
----------------------------
Eva           Apple       6
Bob           Samsung     2
Bob           Apple       1
...           ...        ...
```

How i can setup string for select only rows with MAX values in Column3 ?

My version of string is :

```
SELECT MAX(Column3) , [column2], [Column2] 
FROM Table1
WHERE Column3 =  MAX ;
```

Thanks for Opinions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select max value of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510185/select-max-value-of-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find the maximum Column3 for each combination of Column1 and Column2.

You can achieve this with a GROUP BY

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, MAX(Column3)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Column1, Column2
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql

Comment: its problém wit numbers over 99 and 999

Comment: Are your numbers stored as numbers, or as text?  What sort of problem are you having?

Answer (score 2):

You can use row_number

```
Select top (1) with ties *
   from table1 
   order by row_number() over (partition by Column1, Column2 order by Column3 desc)
```

Other way is to use outer query:

```
Select * from (
   Select *, RowN = row_number() over (partition by Column1, Column2 order by Column3 desc) from table1 ) a
   Where a.RowN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helful!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (
SELECT *, rn=ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by COLUMN1,COLUMN2,Column3 order by 
Column3  desc)
FROM Table1
)
WHERE rn=1
```

Comment: Very low effort answer. Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Partition by will divide the results of table as the Column3 order is by desc order you will get the max result , that is why i have mentioned rn=1. Try Practically its very fast and easily.

Comment: You should add it all in the actual answer, not comments. I'm a reviewer, I'm not asking explanation for myself ;)

Comment: I know, but when the user execute the code the result will be correct.  Next time i will surely add descriptions on my any answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
WITH B AS
(
    SELECT
        Column1, Column2, Column3,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1, Column2 ORDER BY Column3 DESC) AS row_num
    FROM
        Table1
)
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM B
WHERE row_num = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a group by. In queries of this type, you have a set of columns you want the values from (these are the columns you group by) and you have other columns most of whose values you'll throw away. You use a function like MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG to specify what to do with the data from rows that are "thrown away". The result is a unique set of values from the columns that were grouped, and a single value corresponding to the min/max/avg etc from the columns that were not grouped:

```
SELECT [column1], [Column2], MAX(Column3) as Column3
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Column3  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Group by on column 3.

```
Select col1, col2, max(col3)
from test
Group By col3
```

Comment: I thought the column 3 was of integer data type

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like DENSE_RANK().

In this example, if there are duplicate values you want to retrieve.

```
declare @t as table (COLUMN1   char(3),  COLUMN2 varchar(10),   COLUMN3  int)



INSERT @t (COLUMN1    , COLUMN2   , COLUMN3  ) select 'Eva',           'Apple'       ,1
INSERT @t (COLUMN1    , COLUMN2   , COLUMN3  ) select 'Eva',           'Apple'       ,2
INSERT @t (COLUMN1    , COLUMN2   , COLUMN3  ) select 'Eva',           'Apple'       ,3
INSERT @t (COLUMN1    , COLUMN2   , COLUMN3  ) select 'Bob',           'Apple'       ,1
INSERT @t (COLUMN1    , COLUMN2   , COLUMN3  ) select 'Bob',           'Samsung'     ,1
INSERT @t (COLUMN1    , COLUMN2   , COLUMN3  ) select 'Bob',           'Samsung'     ,2


SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2 ORDER BY COLUMN1, COLUMN3 desc)  [Max] , * from @t ) as T
WHERE max = 1 -- Set here what position do you want 
Order by COLUMN3
```