# Get most recent date for each id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the max date for each id in this table

```
ID       Date
___      ____
1     2017-01-01
1     2017-03-01
2     2018-01-01
2     2013-07-03
2     2015-03-02
3     2011-11-11
```

So I'd want something like this returned

```
ID       Date
___      ____
1     2017-03-01
2     2018-01-01
3     2011-11-11
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `MAX(DATE)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select info from table where row has max date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432913/select-info-from-table-where-row-has-max-date)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select max value of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510185/select-max-value-of-each-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select ID, Max(Date) as Date 
from yourtable
group by ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT ID, Date
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, Date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Or `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(Date) AS Date
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```