# Filter a join on each primary-foreign key relation only

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I am using MySql.

I have table `job` that has a primary key `job_pk_id` and the table stores details of every job. Also I have a table `job_running_status` where `job` table's `job_pk_id` is a foreign key and this table basically contains records of when a job ran for each `job_pk_id`.There will be multiple entries for the same `job_pk_id` as the same job runs multiple times. `job_running_status` table also has a field `job_start_time` that gives the start time for each instance of the running of the job.

Now my requirement is to get the latest `job_running_status` for every `job` . The latest `job_running_status` would be chosen based on the latest `job_start_time`(for that particular job only) value in `job_running_status`.

I know this can be achieved using `INNER JOIN` and `ORDER BY job_start_time desc` between `job` table and `job_running_status` table but my challenge is this `ORDER BY` becomes applicable across all the jobs in the `JOIN` but I need to be applicable only across records that are corresponding to a particular job.

`EDIT`
`I understand it might be confusing to understand me by just reading so I am providing some examples:`

`job` table:

[image: Job Table Image]

`job_running_status` table:

[image: job_running_status image]

`My final requirement after joining both the tables`

[image: My final requirement after joining both the tables]

Note: while joining I a should be getting only 1 record corresponding to every JOB table record. This record is chosen based on the latest job_start_time for that JOB.

Comment: Showing some sample data would be nice ^ ^

Comment: 'The latest job_running_status would be chosen based on the latest job_start_time(for that particular job only) value in job_running_status.' You only appear to be selecting 1 record per job so why would you need an order by other than on job?

Comment: 'but I need to be applicable only across records that are corresponding to a particular job.' - so just put a filter if you have that jobname/id

Comment: Search for correlated sub queries.BTW sample data and expected output is better as text , which we can use rather than images which we can't.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Edited my original post to give example.

Comment: @P.Salmon  Edited my original post to give example.

Comment: @AritraBhattacharya  Edited my original post to give example.

Comment: Please: Use text, not images/links, for text (including tables). Read & act on [mcve]. Clarify via post edits, not comments. Also, this is faq; it has a tag; always google many clear concise phrasings of your problem/goal/issue/question & read many answers before considering asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select max value of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510185/select-max-value-of-each-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of a correlated sub query in a where clause

```
drop table if exists t,t1;
create table t(id int);
create table t1(jid int,dt date);
insert into t values
(1),(2),(3);

insert into t1 values
(1,'2018-01-01'),
(1,'2018-02-01'),
(2,'2018-01-01'),
(3,'2018-01-01'),
(3,'2018-02-01'),
(3,'2018-03-01');

select t.id,t1.dt
from t
join t1 on t1.jid = t.id
where t1.dt =(select max(dt) from t1 where t1.jid = t.id);

+------+------------+
| id   | dt         |
+------+------------+
|    1 | 2018-02-01 |
|    2 | 2018-01-01 |
|    3 | 2018-03-01 |
+------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you need the latest n records and you are not on version 8.0 or higher you can use row number simulation

```
select t.id,s.dt
from t
join 
(select t1.jid,t1.dt ,
          if(t1.jid<>@p,@rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
          @p:=t1.jid p
from t1 
cross join (select @rn:=0,@p:=0) r
order by t1.jid ,t1.dt desc
) s on s.jid = t.id
where s.rn <= 2;

+------+------------+
| id   | dt         |
+------+------------+
|    1 | 2018-01-01 |
|    1 | 2018-02-01 |
|    2 | 2018-01-01 |
|    3 | 2018-02-01 |
|    3 | 2018-03-01 |
+------+------------+
```

Comment: Got it,it was helpful

Comment: This query gives the latest record(i.e 1 record). Is there any way to get more than 1 record using the same criteria that is I want to get the latest 2 job running instances for a job record?

Comment: That's scope creep. Your question should have been how can I get the latest n records. And no you cannot use this method. I will add code for this shortly.

Comment: Ooops, sorry mate....sure add the code...I will edit the title on the original post

Comment: Er why?The edit I added 2 days ago starting 'If you need the latest n records ...' covers your requirement.

Comment: I did not get the part in the query where you used symbol like '@'. For eg. "if(t1.jid<>@p,@rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
          @p:=t1.jid p". Can you give me some keyword to lookup on google so that I can learn use of such syntax

Comment: The keyword is row number simulation have a look at this http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query. `CROSS JOIN` with subquery, which get `MAX(job_running_status)`

Then join `job` and `job_running_status` tables.

**TestDLL**

```
CREATE TABLE JOB(
   job_pk_id int
);

INSERT INTO JOB VALUES (1),(2),(3);


CREATE TABLE job_running_status(
   fk_job_id INT,
   job_running_status DATE
);

INSERT INTO  job_running_status VALUES (1,'2018-01-01');
INSERT INTO  job_running_status VALUES (1,'2018-02-01');
INSERT INTO  job_running_status VALUES (2,'2018-01-03');
INSERT INTO  job_running_status VALUES (2,'2018-01-02');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    j.job_pk_id,
    jrs.fk_job_id,
    t.job_running_status
FROM 
(SELECT MAX(job_running_status) job_running_status FROM job_running_status) t
CROSS JOIN job j 
inner join job_running_status  jrs on j.job_pk_id = jrs.fk_job_id
```

**[Results]**:

```
| job_pk_id | fk_job_id | job_running_status |
|-----------|-----------|--------------------|
|         1 |         1 |         2018-02-01 |
|         2 |         2 |         2018-02-01 |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1ce8b/3)

Comment: Got it,it was helpful

Comment: This query gives the latest record(i.e 1 record). Is there any way to get more than 1 record using the same criteria that is I want to get the latest 2 job running instances for a job record?

Comment: Do you want to use `MAX` like this?  `SELECT  
    j.job_pk_id,
    jrs.fk_job_id,
    MAX(t.job_running_status) job_running_status
FROM 
job j 
inner join job_running_status  jrs on j.job_pk_id = jrs.fk_job_id
GROUP BY     
    j.job_pk_id,
    jrs.fk_job_id`

Comment: Can I have some rectification please: before the `FROM` you have written `job_running_status` which is a table name. Is is intentional or just a typo ?