# select max value of each group including other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

[Select max value of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510185/select-max-value-of-each-group)

In the mentioned Question there is solution to take the max value of each group. I need some more help I want both  the max value of each group and another column(third column in question) for that max value. Table looks like this

```
Name  Value AnotherColumn
Pump1 1000   1
Pump1 2000   2
Pump2 1000   2
Pump2 2000   1
```

Output should be

```
Name  Value AnotherColumn
Pump1 2000    2
Pump2 2000    1
```

I am using Microsoft Sql Server 2012. Another column can be of any type, it is not restricted to integer, I just want to get the another column for the max value of each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option uses `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT Name, Value, AnotherColumn
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Value DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Note that if you want all ties per name with regard to largest value, then you may replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK` (or maybe `DENSE_RANK`), to get all ties.

Comment: This helped!  Your answer is detailed,  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use row_number() function:

```
select * from 
(select *, row_number() over (partition by name order by value desc) as rn)a
where rn=1
```

Comment: You were first to answer but its not detailed. I have +1 your answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

simply use `group by` and `max()`

```
select name ,max(value), max(AnotherColumn) 
from t group by Name
```

you can use co-related subquery

```
 select * from t t1
   where t1.value in (select max(t2.value) from t t2 where t1.name=t2.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a subquery in `where` to make it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM T t1
WHERE Value = (
    SELECT MAX(Value) 
    FROM T tt
    WHERE tt.Name  = t1.Name  
)
```

Comment: let us assume if a max value of one group is 3 but other group also has it but its not max of that group. Both will get selected then and also = should not be operator in the query.